# Getting NullPointerException with row.setAttribute on Oracle ADF

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, weblogic, jdeveloper, oracle-adf

I'm now trying to learn Oracle ADF and I'm getting a NullPointerException while running the following code on a Java bean.
Can you help me figure out what I'm doing wrong please? This is being invoked from a button on a JSPX page.

```
public String cb1_action() {
    try{
        BindingContext bindingctx = BindingContext.getCurrent();
        BindingContainer bindings = bindingctx.getCurrentBindingsEntry();
        DCBindingContainer bindingsImpl = (DCBindingContainer)bindings;
        DCIteratorBinding iter = bindingsImpl.findIteratorBinding("ViewObj1Iterator");


        Row row = iter.getCurrentRow();

        row.setAttribute("Id", 123);
        row.setAttribute("Nome", "Pedro Teste");

    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Excepcao em: ");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

According to the Stack trace, the error occurs on the first row.setAttribute() line.
Also, I'm using the latest version of JDeveloper with the integrated WebLogic server.

Best regards,

Pedro

Comment: `row` could be `null` (i.e `getCurrentRow()` returns `null`)!

Comment: debug and see if you are getting the ->  bindingsImpl.findIteratorBinding("ViewObj1Iterator");

Comment: usual scenario if you are doing something wrong and you need to check your mind against the problem. But it may cause a poor system design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so here's how I figured out how to get around this:

First, I asked jDeveloper to generate a class for the Application Module.
In that class, I added the following methods:

```
public void testEntityObject()
{
    System.out.println("Let's try our Entity Object...");

    try
    {
        EntityDefImpl entity = TesteEOImpl.getDefinitionObject();
        TesteEOImpl ti = (TesteEOImpl)entity.createInstance2(getDBTransaction(), null);
        ti.setId(new BigDecimal(123));
        ti.setNome("Entity Object test...");

        getDBTransaction().commit();

        System.out.println("Looks good :-)");
    }
    catch(Exception e) 
    {
        System.out.println("It seems something went wrong :-(");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void testViewObject() {
    System.out.println("Let's try our View Object...");

            ViewObjectImpl vo = this.getTeste1();

        try{
            Row row = vo.createRow();
            row.setAttribute("Id", 234);
            row.setAttribute("Nome", "VO test");
            vo.insertRow(row);
            getDBTransaction().commit();
            System.out.println("Looks good :-)")
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("It seems something went wrong :-(");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

These methods are being called by a managed bean that is connected to two buttons on the page. This managed bean has the following methods. I'll post just one of them as only the method names change:

```
public String cb1_action() {

    try{
    FacesContext fctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(); 
    BindingContext bindingContext = BindingContext.getCurrent();
    DCDataControl dc = bindingContext.findDataControl("AppModuleAMDataControl");
    AppModuleAMImpl am = (AppModuleAMImpl)dc.getDataProvider();


    am.criarTesteComEntityObject();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

I know this is not rocket science or anything but it took a while for me to get there...
Basically, your answers helped me a lot to go and investigate what was happening. The cause? Poor design! ADF is supposed to be organized...
Thank you everyone! :D

Answer (score 2):

```
Row row = iter.getCurrentRow();
if(row  != null){
    row.setAttribute("Id", 123);
    row.setAttribute("Nome", "Pedro Teste"); //name?
}
```

Comment: That would stop the exceptions from being thrown but it still wouldn't solve my issue...

Answer (score 1):

The info that you get the error at

> row.setAttribute("Id", 123);

let me think that you try to alter the primary key attribute of the row, which is not allowed. Not sure about this as you did not mention the error you get.

Comment: Nope.. That was not the issue. I tried without primary keys (just ROWID) and it didn't work properly either. But thanks for the tip.